# Python pandas add N multiplied by the value of the current second and add with the value of N multiplied by the value of the previous second

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file in which I would like to make some calculation.

My csv looks something like this:

| Time | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 4 | 1 |
| 10:00:01 | 5 | 0 |
| 10:00:02 | 4 | 4 |
| 10:00:03 | 5 | 3 |
| 10:00:04 | 4 | 1 |
| 10:00:05 | 5 | 2 |
| 10:00:06 | 4 | 4 |
| 10:00:07 | 5 | 8 |
| 10:00:08 | 4 | 4 |
| 10:00:09 | 5 | 8 |

In the background, I add the variable N = 10

And I would like to add a new column to the same csv file with a calculation using the formula

Something like N + 1 * Value 1 of its own line + N+ 1 * Value 2 of the previous line

To get something like this:

| Time | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 4 | 1 | 44 |
| 10:00:01 | 5 | 0 | 66 |
| 10:00:02 | 4 | 4 | 44 |
| 10:00:03 | 5 | 3 | 99 |
| 10:00:04 | 4 | 1 | 77 |
| 10:00:05 | 5 | 2 | 66 |
| 10:00:06 | 4 | 4 | 66 |
| 10:00:07 | 5 | 8 | 99 |
| 10:00:08 | 4 | 4 | 132 |
| 10:00:09 | 5 | 8 | 99 |

I tried something like

`out = df.groupby(['Time']) out = %N+1 * df['Value1'] + %N+1 * df['Value2']`

But it doesn't quite work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['10:00:00', 4, 1], ['10:00:01', 5, 0]],
    columns=['Time', 'Value1', 'Value2']
)

N = 10
df['Value3'] = (N + 1) * (df.Value1 + df.Value2.shift(1))
print(df)
```

prints

| index | Time | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10:00:00 | 4 | 1 | NaN |
| 1 | 10:00:01 | 5 | 0 | 66.0 |